# How to find a node in any XML in powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have simple xml

```
<bds>
    <bd>
        <id>10</id>
        <user>john</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc24</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
    <bd>
        <id>12</id>
        <user>peter</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc25</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
</bds>
```

I would like to know how to get the value of `<name>` even if the structure of the previous nodes changes

That is, how can I roam the XML to get the value of the name tag without knowing the name of the previous nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath for that:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<bds>
    <bd>
        <id>10</id>
        <user>john</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc24</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
    <bd>
        <id>12</id>
        <user>peter</user>
        <servers>
            <name>pc25</name> 
        </servers>
    </bd>
</bds>
"@

$xml.SelectNodes('//name').'#text'
```

Output

```
pc24
pc25
```